# Integration of a sequence of bounded functions wihout an upperbound $\mu-integrable$ function $g$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

*Let be $\mu:S\rightarrow[0, +\infty]$ positive measure on $S \  \sigma-algebra$ on $X$ such that $\mu(X)<+\infty$, and a $f_n:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K} \ (n \geq 1)$ a sequence of $S-measurable$ functions, and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ a function such that:
$$\forall n\geq1, \ f_n \ is \   bounded$$
$$f_n \ is  \  uniformly  \ convergent  \ to  \ f \ on \ X \ for \ n\rightarrow+\infty$$
Prove that $f_n$ and $f$ are $\mu-integrable \  (\int_X|f|d\mu, \int_X|f_n|d\mu<+\infty$) on $X$ and prove that: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu=0$$ also prove that this is false if $\mu(X) = +\infty$.*

So, I was able to prove that $f_n$ is $\mu-integrable$, and I know I have to use the dominated convergence theorem, but I don't know how to find an upperbound $\mu-integrable$ function $g$ to use the theorem. Any help?

Comment: You do not need any upper bound. If $\|f_n-f\|_\infty < \varepsilon,$ then $\int_X |f_n(x)-f(x)|d\mu(x) \le \mu(X)\, \varepsilon.$

Comment: Yeah ok, but how do I prove that $\int_X|f|d\mu<+\infty$? And for the last question, I just need to prove that $\int_X|f_n|d\mu > \int_Xm<+\infty d\mu$ where for any $n$ I have $|f_n|>m$, am I right?

Comment: The function $f$ is bounded as the uniform limit of bounded functions $f_n.$ If $\|f_n-f\|_\infty <\varepsilon,$ then by the triangle inequality $\|f\|_\infty <\|f_n\|_\infty +\varepsilon.$ I do not quite get the second question.

Comment: If $g(x)\le h(x)$ then $\int_Xg(x)\,dx \le \int_Xh(x)\,dx.$ So if $m\le |f_n(x)|$ then
$m\,\mu(X)= \int_X m\,dx\le \int_X|f_n(x)|\,dx.$

Comment: The only problem is, how can I be sure that this $m$ exists? Can I simply take $m=\inf_{x\in X}\{\min_{n\geq1}f_n\}$? But what if $m=-\infty$?

Comment: I do not get it, $|f_n(x)|\ge 0.$

Comment: I mean, I wrote a really dumb thing, that should solves, thanks @RyszardSzwarc